# I have created inverted index for a website but where to store that? Database for a search engine?

Tags: database, search-engine, inverted-index

What can be the database for a search engine? I mean after creating inverted index for a site, where one could store it so that program can create indices for other sites and save them too. Later on indexer can query them also.
Because indices can range in thousands of billions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/).  That's what it is made for.  You even have your choice of many different languages.